# Send Email with attachment php

Tags: php

I try the following code to send email with attachment but it only display text as below

```
$filename = basename($file);
$file_size = filesize($file);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode(file_get_contents($file))); //echo $content; exit(0);
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));     
$message .= $content."\r\n\r\n"
."--".$uid."--";
```

iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAABVYAAAMACAIAAABAXKuVAAAAAXNSR0IArs4c6QAAAARnQU1BAACx jwv8YQUAAAAJcEhZcwAADsMAAA7DAcdvqGQAAAASdEVYdFNvZnR3YXJlAEdyZWVuc2hvdF5VCAUA AP+HSURBVHhe7J0HXBXH2v/5317ee9/bcpPb3pvkJrlJboqpNz0xMaYXE001PTG9GGOLNfYOIkqR IqggiF1BUHoTUVCkg/QiHYFz4Aic839mZ3d2dnbP4VBMLM/z+brOzj4zOztnds88v7O7uPzqqk+G k6s/+TXhU5FrPv0flc9U/v3ZbzR8LnMt4bcC131B+V+B6ylf/k7gP4yvfs9zg8ofCBNlblT5I+Om r3n+xLgZmMRzCWUE4xvKnym3CEy+lHKrnimX3WbMX24Hpur56x2MaRrunPY3lekq/53+d5Fv/34X 4R967gZm/J+eeygz/ylwr8zlhFkq98lcoTL7ivs1XMl4YA7PvxgPUuZSrmI8xPPd1YyRAvOuAR42 4N/AI/P1XAuMoiwQuO5RxkKe60cLLCI8tug/hjy+GLhBzxPAkhv1PEm4ibBUw1OEm1WWEZ5WGaGy fMQzKrfwPAusoNzK8xxlJeU2yvMCq26njBG5g+B6xwsid1JedNPzX2AsZTXPXeME3Cl3v6RnDeHl NfcY8orHvYa86nEfYa2G12TuJ6xTeV3mARVPwniZBwXe8KI8JPAm4E0ZyXiLx+dhxtsaHiGsJ7wj MorgO+pdkUcp7wF+PKOB93n8KY8BHwgEUB6fYMiGJz405smPgECRjwlPEYI0fEJ4WmWjzKeEZ0Q2 PfOZzLMCn2+mPMfzBSP4eZ4vVcYQQmS+0vACYQthooYXGV+H8oylTGKEMcYB3/BspbwETNYT/jIw xZhXpm4zYNq2VwnbRaZvf01lh8q3O17XsFNmBmG8wMxdlDcEZlF2vykwm7HnLZ45Km8T9srMVXmH 8d0+nncZ84AInvco8xmRlPcpCwT2f0BZqCdqwiJjPlwMROv5aAnjgIalBz5WOaiy7OAnIjGfLCd8 qmcFEPuZnpWUuM8FVsl8QYhXcZX5UiXhSzcNXzFWJ/JMZLhTkihfM9bwJE9ieAikfAOsNWAysC5V zxTAk5ImMNWLcYhnmrdAOsEnfboh6w8D3

Hope someone will help. Thanks in advanced.

Comment: dont build your own, use phpmailer

Comment: Show your complete MIME structure.